# Selenium: Cannot fill the input field with Send Keys and Executing Script

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I need to make a login script for the website https://cbdbene.com/

[image: Login Page]

but when I try to send Keys to the email field, I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I have tried using,

```
login_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_email']")
driver.execute_script("argument[0].setAttribute('value', 'abs@gmail.com');", login_email)
```

but that is also of no help,

Even clicking the element has no response,

```
login_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_email']")
driver.execute_script("argument[0].click();", login_email)
```

I don't know how to fill this form. Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.get("https://cbdbene.com/")



warning = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-dismiss']//i//*[local-name()='svg']")))
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys("Keys.ESCAPE")

warning.click()


loginIcon = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[3]//span[1]//div[1]//div[1]//*[local-name()='svg']")))
loginIcon.click()

inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[4]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//span[1]//input[1]")))
inputBox.send_keys("Username")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Trying the above solution raises `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue? your site taking too long to load if you are facing any TimeoutException then change WebDriverWait as per your convenient time

Comment: @kunal: check updated solution to stop page loading and its working fine foor me

Comment: Yes, now it's working fine. I don't know why, when I use the XPATH `//*[@id="login_email"]`, it does not work, but using the full XPATH, it works fine.

Comment: because its returning list of elements

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute xpath you will see 3 inputs elements are there with same property.
Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and use valid xpath.samething you have do with password.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://cbdbene.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.modal-dismiss"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.c-nav__list-item>span.c-nav__link"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='login_email'])[last()]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='login_email'])[last()]"))).send_keys("user name")

Browser snapshot:
```

[image]